# RSS feed is not available with Typo3 11.5.27 and tx_news 11.0.0

Tags: typo3, tx-news

Since updating to tx_news 11.0.0 the RSS-Feed dont work anymore. Using "RSS feed by TypoScript" as described in the documentation under best practice (https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.0/en-us/Tutorials/BestPractice/Rss/Index.html#rss-feed-by-typoscript).

Didn't change anything so far. Hope it is an bug that will be fixed soon.

Comment: "does not work" is not helpful. which result do you get?

Comment: Please provide the installation steps, code (if any), what did you expect and what you got.

Comment: @GeorgRinger The file is empty. No characters are delivered. The feed worked perfectly before the 11.0.0 update. No changes were made to the configuration. The error log shows nothing. My System:TYPO3-Version 11.5.27
Webserver Apache
PHP-Version 8.1.13
Datenbank (Default) MySQL 8.0.25
Anwendungskontext Production
Betriebssystem Linux 5.4.0-117-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was:

```
pageNewsRSS.10.settings.categories = [empty]
```

I don't use categories, so I left it blank. Befor version 11 it seems to be no problem.